# How do I set a splash screen in landscape mode on an iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a portrait splash screen name, but it's not working in landscape mode.

Like this:

1. Default.png
2. Default2@x.png
3. Default-568h@2x.png
4. Default-Portrait.png
5. Default-Landscape.png

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's Documentation

Each orientation-specific launch image must include a special modifier string in its filename. The format for orientation-specific launch image filenames is as follows:

```
<basename><orientation_modifier><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png
```

Eg :

```
1)    Default-Portrait.png
2)    Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png
3)    Default-Landscape.png
4)    Default-LandscapeLeft.png
5)    Default-LandscapeRight.png
```

Note : These modifiers are supported for launch images used in iPad apps only.

So you have to change your Image according to the Orientation for iPhone.

Two ways to do that :

1) Rotating the Splash Image to 90 Degree.

2) Inverting the Dimensions (320 * 480 -> 480 * 320).